# Powershell script work in powershell but not in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

Below scripts format work for me in powershell to remove package from another user but its not working on C#

other script working fine in c# like get all package , remove package for all user , I run the visual studio as Admin

I am writing this in WPF application

There is no error or bug in code its just executed without error but app state not change

after running script from powershell its work fine
after running script from c# application status updated as 'NeedsRemediation'

Format

```
Get-AppxPackage -User SID | Where PackageFullName -eq packagefullname | Remove-AppxPackage -User

Remove-AppxPackage -Package packagefullname -User SID
```

script

```
Get-AppxPackage -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009 | Where PackageFullName -eq FACEBOOK.FACEBOOK_2021.927.1.0_neutral__8xx8rvfyw5nnt | Remove-AppxPackage -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009

Remove-AppxPackage -Package 5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_2.2216.8.0_x64__cv1g1gvanyjgm -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009
```

C#

```cs
using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInst.AddScript(removeCommand, false);
    var PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();
    if (PowerShellInst.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not seeing errors, the implication is that your `Where` (`Where-Object`) call found no matching package(s).

Comment: Remove-AppxPackage -Package 5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_2.2216.8.0_x64__cv1g1gvanyjgm -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009

@mklement0 same issue for below query

Comment: @ArjunBalip - any updates to your question should be in your question, as an edit, and not as a comment. Even more important when sharing something that needs to be formatted (like code or PowerShell)

Comment: @ArjunBalip please don't reply to queries for clarification in comments. Instead, [edit] the question to make it clear what you are doing and what you have tried.